# Parent null in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a `Group` class that allows nested Groups.  My setup is like so:

```
class Group
{
    [InverseProperty("Children")]
    public Group Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Children { get; set; }
}
```

If I retrieve a folder with children, they are populated and their Parent field is filled in.  If I just get a child folder directly `Parent` is null.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Group.Parent` isn't virtual. Hence, lazy loading doesn't triggers here.
Either make it virtual, or use `Include(g => g.Parent)`, when loading child directly.